# What is the connection settings from outside for a mongoDB running in amazon EC2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm probably missing something pretty obvious, but I can't connect to a mongoDB running on amazon cloud. Here is what I did:

I successfully initiated a mongoDB replica set in amazon EC2 following this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/mongodb/welcome.html

I use mongoDB for a parse server installation that runs on heroku. To finish the configuration, I would need to configure parse-server to talk to the new database.

despite the facts that

- I can connect to the linux bastion created in EC2 via ssh,
- and from there I can connect to the primary replica node via ssh
- and from there I can connect locally to the mongoDB via the mongo cli,

I can't find a way to connect to mongoDB directly without going through ssh.

I configured amazon to allow connections from everywhere (just for now), and my `etc/mongod.conf` has these lines:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIpAll: true
```

The PrimaryNode in EC2 console does NOT have a public IP.

I'm trying to connect to the mongoDB using the mongod admin username and password to the elastic IP of the bastion, but my mongoclident can't connect.

```
$ mongo admin@eXXXX.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:2721
MongoDB shell version v3.4.9
connecting to: admin@ eXXXX.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:2721
2018-08-22T12:30:42.262+0200 I NETWORK  [thread1] getaddrinfo("admin@ eXXXX.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com") failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
2018-08-22T12:30:42.266+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't initialize connection to host admin@ eXXXX.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com, address is invalid :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: Does the host you're trying to connect to have a public IP on a private subnet?

Comment: The Linux Bastion has a public IP. The replica set instances have only private IPs

Comment: If it is for dev purposes, you can create an ssh tunnel through the bastion. Otherwise you need public IPs for all of your mongo instances.